# Launcher cannot connect to App Engine Servers

Tags: google-app-engine

My website has been running well for a month now. Everything looks fine in the admin console and server logs. However, whenever I try using the Launcher to deploy, I receive the following error:

```
12:25 AM Getting current resource limits.
2013-01-23 00:25:36,056 ERROR appcfg.py:2203 An error occurred processing file '': <urlopen error [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it>. Aborting. 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\appcfg.py", line 171, in <module>
    run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\appcfg.py", line 167, in run_file
    execfile(script_path, globals_)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 4377, in <module>
    main(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 4368, in main
    result = AppCfgApp(argv).Run()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 2605, in Run
    self.action(self)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 4103, in __call__
    return method()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 3115, in Update
    self.UpdateVersion(rpcserver, self.basepath, appyaml)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 3097, in UpdateVersion
    return appversion.DoUpload(paths, openfunc)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 2173, in DoUpload
    self.resource_limits = GetResourceLimits(self.rpcserver, self.config)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 358, in GetResourceLimits
    resource_limits.update(GetRemoteResourceLimits(rpcserver, config))
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 329, in GetRemoteResourceLimits
    version=config.version)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appengine_rpc.py", line 391, in Send
    f = self.opener.open(req)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 400, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 418, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 378, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 1215, in https_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPSConnection, req)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\fancy_urllib\fancy_urllib\__init__.py", line 383, in do_open
    raise url_error
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it>
2013-01-23 00:25:36 (Process exited with code 1)
```

In fact, even using Help -> Check For Updates... displays the following warnings:

```
Cannot perform proper version check.
cannot_contact_server
release: "1.7.4"
timestamp: 1352314290
api_versions: ['1']
```

Does anybody know what could be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that I had environment variables named `http_proxy` and `https_proxy` set that Python's urllib2 uses to route all connections through a proxy. Removing those environment variables fixes the issue.